# can we modify private variables in child class

Tags: java

> can we *modify* a private variable through **child class**. 
> We can use it by set and get methods but how can we modify them in child class.

Comment: It is *private* and hence you cannot access it directly

Comment: What is your set method doing? Is not it setting the value of the field ?

Comment: i wann to modify the value through child calss

Comment: setter getter methods doing fine in parent class

Comment: Calling `set` *is* modifying the variable, right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a **direct** access to `private` members of parent class through child class. You can specify **getters** and **setters** with `protected` or `public` access modifier in parent class and change or read value of that `private` member of parent class by calling proper method - getter or setter.

Example of how you can achieve that:

```
class Parent {
    private int member;
    public void setMember(int member) { // setter
        this.member = member;
    }
    public int getMember() { // getter
        return member;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {}

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Child child = new Child();
        System.out.println("member = " + child.getMember());
        child.setMember(5);
        System.out.println("member = " + child.getMember());
    }
}
```

Output that you get:

```
member = 0
member = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot modify private variables in a super class, unless you are using reflection.

The only way to access them would be getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change private from the other class.
You can change in the same class

```
class Parent {

private value;

public class Method {
System.out.println(value++);
}
           
}
```